# android application running in simulator but not in mobile devices

Tags: android

Recently I've created one android application using eclipse and ran it using android virtual device manager. It ran successfully in the simulator, but whenever I am trying to install it in mobile device HTC Salsa (2.3 ginger bread) it is showing an error message and not proceeding. The error message is:

> Parse Error: There is a problem parsing the package

As it was my first demo application in android so it will be very helpful if you will guide me in this.

Comment: How are you "installing" it? Running it directly on the device from Eclipse? If you create a new demo application, does it work?

Comment: @Paul-Jan No actually whenever i build the project in eclipse it automatically creates the .apk file in the bin folder. The same .apk file I'm transferring to the mobile device and trying to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue, it was happening because of the API version. I have the target version as 4.0.3 i.e, API 15 but ginger bread is of API 10. So I've modified the line `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />` in manifest file to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />`. Now it is working fine. Thanks for all of your help...

Answer (score 0):

Try to "clean" then "rebuild" your project.